# truncate three near-identical subs in userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multi-page userform I'm using to pull very simple metrics (page 1 is home page, page 2 is name, page 3 is birthday, page 4 is gender).

I have a private sub for each button on each multi-page for each command button to pull in the data from each excel sheet back to the userform based on an employee ID lookup. How can I truncate these three subs into something more compact? Should I put them in modules and `call` each one from the userform code?

```
Private Sub cmdPullName_Click() 'pull employee name in useform based on ID # 
    lpersonID = InputBox("Please enter the employees ID #")
    If lpersonID = "false" Then Exit Sub
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    matched = False
    Set wsTgt = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rFound = wsTgt.Columns("A").Find(lpersonID, wsTgt.Cells(wsTgt.Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address
            Do
            If rFound.Value = lpersonID Then
                matched = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set rFound = wsTgt.Columns("A").FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
        End If
        If matched Then
            Me.txtPersonID.Value = wsTgt.Cells(rFound.Row, 1).Value
            Me.txtName.Value = wsTgt.Cells(rFound.Row, 2).Value
        Else
            MsgBox ("Record not found")
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub cmdPullBday_Click() 'pull employee bday in useform based on ID # 
    lpersonID = InputBox("Please enter the employees ID #")
    If lpersonID = "false" Then Exit Sub
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    matched = False
    Set wsTgt = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rFound = wsTgt.Columns("A").Find(lpersonID_2, wsTgt.Cells(wsTgt.Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address
            Do
            If rFound.Value = lpersonID Then
                matched = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set rFound = wsTgt.Columns("A").FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
        End If
        If matched Then
            Me.txtpersonID_2.Value = wsTgt.Cells(rFound.Row, 1).Value
            Me.txtBday.Value = wsTgt.Cells(rFound.Row, 2).Value
        Else
            MsgBox ("Record not found")
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub cmdPullGender_Click() 'pull employee gender in useform based on ID # 
    lpersonID = InputBox("Please enter the employees ID #")
    If lpersonID = "false" Then Exit Sub
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    matched = False
    Set wsTgt = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set rFound = wsTgt.Columns("A").Find(lpersonID_3, wsTgt.Cells(wsTgt.Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address
            Do
            If rFound.Value = lpersonID Then
                matched = True
            Exit Do
            End If
            Set rFound = wsTgt.Columns("A").FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
        End If
        If matched Then
            Me.txtPersonID_3.Value = wsTgt.Cells(rFound.Row, 1).Value
            Me.cmbGender.Value = wsTgt.Cells(rFound.Row, 2).Value
        Else
            MsgBox ("Record not found")
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If this code is working but you're looking for efficiency, shouldn't this be in CodeReview?

Comment: Look at the 3 subs and identify what is common across them, and move that into a a standalone sub or function.  Whatever is variable becomes an input (parameter) in that method.

Comment: @ChrisH. Just because a Question _might_ be on topic on CR, doesn't make it off topic here.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in that `Find` loop?  You're using `lookat:=xlWhole` so any match found will be an exact/full match, so I'm not clear what the purpose of the following `Do...Loop While` is?  Seems like that could all be replaced with a `vlookup()`

Comment: @ChrisH going along with what ChrisNeilsen stated: Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353). I see you have a CR account but it might also be helpful to read this if you haven't already: [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```vb
Private Sub cmdPullName_Click() 'pull employee name in useform based on ID #
    EmployeeInfo ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), Me.txtName
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPullBday_Click() 'pull employee bday in useform based on ID #
    EmployeeInfo ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2"), Me.txtBday
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPullGender_Click() 'pull employee gender in useform based on ID #
    EmployeeInfo ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3"), Me.cmbGender
End Sub

Sub EmployeeInfo(sourceSheet As Worksheet, ctlInfo As Object)
    Dim lpersonID, res
    
    lpersonID = InputBox("Please enter the employee's ID #", "Employee Id")
    If lpersonID = "false" Then Exit Sub
    
    res = Application.VLookup(lpersonID, sourceSheet.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    If IsError(res) Then
        MsgBox "No match found for " & lpersonID & " on " & sourceSheet.Name, vbExclamation
    Else
        Me.txtPersonID.Value = lpersonID
        ctlInfo.Value = res
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this works great, but quick question: if I have more to fill in than just one value (name), and a ton of different fields that I'll build into the userform, will I just add that below `ctlInfo.value = res`?

Comment: I can't predict exactly what you'd need to do.  Your approach seems a bit off though - why not prompt the user just once for the id and then fill in all of the matching information from the various sheets?  And is there a reson the employee info is all stored on separate worksheets?

Comment: yes, the reasoning being that this is just a dummy userform. when I build out the actual multi-page form, each sheet will need to house separate sets of data. My question is, will I be able to fill out explicitly which column in found row corresponds with each field in the userform? I see you have `ctlInfo.value = res`, but not sure if that only works here because im just trying to retrieve the name and not multiple fields from the worksheet.

Comment: Multiple fields would be a different situation from the code you posted.  It's difficult to generalize on code you haven't yet written, but you should be able to get the general idea of extracting the common parts of your code and passing arguments to it for the variable parts.